# Create new frame with new contents python

Tags: python, tkinter

How can i create a new frame and pass the values to it through python?

Code:

```
 import Tkinter as tk
 import tkMessageBox
 import json
 import requests
 from urllib import urlopen
 import os.path
 import threading
```

class myapp(tk.Frame):

```
def callfunc(self,title = "", author = "", body = ""):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, top)
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(top, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
    self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(top, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

    self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                              tags="self.frame")

    self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
    print title
    data_json = ""
    L1 = tk.Label(self, text="Title")
    L1.pack()
    E1 = tk.Entry(self, bd =5)
    E1.pack()
    #E1.insert(0,title)

    L2 = tk.Label(self, text="Author")
    L2.pack( )
    E2 = tk.Entry(self, bd =5)
    E2.pack()
    #E2.insert(0,author)

    L3 = tk.Label(self, text="Body")
    L3.pack( )
    E3 = tk.Entry(self, bd =5)
    E3.pack()
    #E3.insert(0,body)
    if (title !=""):
        data = {"author": E2.get(),
        "body" : E3.get(),
        "title" : E1.get()}
        data_json = json.dumps(data)
    self.SubmitButton = tk.Button(self,text="Submit", fg="White", bg="#0094FF", 
                                font=("Grobold", 10), command = lambda: self.submitfunc(data_json))
    self.SubmitButton.pack()
    #SubmitButton.pack()

def submitfunc(self,data_json):
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    url = 'http://localhost/spritle/api.php?action=insert_list&data_json='
    check = self.connected_to_internet(url)
    if(check):
        r = requests.post(url+data_json ,headers=headers )
        print r.status_code
        # if (r.status_code == 200):
        #     tkMessageBox.showinfo("Result","success")
        # else:
        #     if(os.path.isfile("offline_post.json")):
        #         with open('offline_post.json','a') as f:
        #             f.write(data_json+"\n")
        #     else:
        #         open('offline_post.json', 'a')
        #         with open('offline_post.json','a') as f:
        #             f.write(data_json+"\n")

# homeButton = Button(text="Home", fg="White", bg="#0094FF", 
#                               font=("Grobold", 10), command = view)
# homeButton.pack()

def connected_to_internet(self,url, timeout=5):
    try:
        _ = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        #threading.Timer(10, connected_to_internet(url)).start()
        #print "asd"
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("No internet connection available.")
        return False

def onFrameConfigure(self,event):
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


def __init__(self, parent):        
    self.home()

def home(self):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, top)
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(top, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
    self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(top, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

    self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                              tags="self.frame")

    self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
    self.row=0
    # url = "http://localhost/spritle/api.php?action=get_users";
    # r = requests.get(url)
    # j = r.json()
    E1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Title")
    E1.grid(row=self.row, column=0)
    E1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Author")
    E1.grid(row=self.row, column=1)
    E1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text="Body")
    E1.grid(row=self.row, column=2)
    j = [[0 for x in range(5)] for x in range(5)] 
    # j[0]['title'] = "asdg"
    # j[0]['author'] = "asdg"
    # j[0]['body'] = "asdg"
    print j
    for val in j:
        self.row += 1
        T1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text=val)
        T1.grid(row=self.row, column=0)
        A1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text=val)
        A1.grid(row=self.row, column=1)
        B1 = tk.Label(self.frame, text=val)
        B1.grid(row=self.row, column=2)
        editButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Edit", fg="White", bg="#0094FF", 
                                 font=("Grobold", 10),command = lambda title=val,author=val,body=val: self.callfunc(title,author,body))
        editButton.grid(row=self.row,column=3)
    #     editButton.pack()
    newButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text="New Post", fg="White", bg="#0094FF",
                                 font=("Grobold", 10),command =  lambda:self.callfunc)
    newButton.grid(row = self.row + 1, column = 2)

 top = tk.Tk()
 top.title("App")
 sizex = 400
 sizey = 300
 posx  = 50
 posy  = 50
 top.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))
 app = myapp(top)
 top.mainloop()
```

I am new GUI programmer. Is there a way to do it? Or can i overwrite the old frame itself?
Tried with the same frame but the contents are not overriding it display every thing ....

Comment: I am confused.. why are callfunc and home both calling Frame.__init__ and both using `top` the global variable?

Comment: oh, I think I understand you want a new window to open with content in it right? ok let me see if I can give you an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be confusing Frames with Toplevels (windows) a Frame is just a generic container that when not given a parent will generate a window of it's own but to create new windows you will need to make a Toplevel widget:

```
class EXAMPLE_APP(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master.title("still a master")

        self.windows = []
        self.new_button = tk.Button(self,text="make a new window",command=self.new_window)
        self.new_button.grid()
        self.del_button = tk.Button(self,text="delete a window",command=self.del_window)
        self.del_button.grid()

    def new_window(self,event=None):
        new = tk.Toplevel(self)
        new.title("window %d"%len(self.windows))
        tmp_label = tk.Label(new,text="here is the label")
        tmp_label.grid() 
        #it is only temporary because reference is lost when the function finishes, it would be much preferable to have a separate class
        self.windows.append(new)

    def del_window(self,event=None):
        self.windows.pop().destroy()

app = EXAMPLE_APP() #note that you don't have to explicitly specify a root
app.grid() #still have to grid the Frame to its master

app.mainloop()
```

if the new window needs to have stuff on it (which of course it does!) then you may consider making a class just for the popup:

```
class Popup(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,tk_master,title=None,author=None,body=None):
        #most of this code is from your callfunc() method, just changed what is master to widgets
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self,tk_master)
        if title:
            self.title(title)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")
        ...

    def onFrameConfigure(self,event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))



class myapp(tk.Frame):
    def callfunc(self,title = "", author = "", body = ""):
        popup = Popup(self.parent,title,author,body)

    ...

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent  = parent
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.parent) #wouldn't this make more sense in __init__?
        ...
```

Comment: `def new_window(self,event=None):
        new = tk.Toplevel(self)
        new.title("windkmow %d"%len(self.windows))
        L1 = new.Label(self, text="Title")
        L1.grid()
        E1 = new.Entry(self, bd =5)
        E1.grid()
        #E1.insert(0,title)`
How can i include new label in pop up window?

Comment: @user3041822 use  `new` as parent `Label(new, ...)`,  `Entry(new, ...)`

Comment: in that context self is the first window, so if it is the master the widgets will .grid() to the main window, but new represents the new window, I will update my answer to include this.